# Trying to figure out how to use append() to create a list like the second one; it makes an additional tuple not in OG list

Tags: python, list, append

```
data = [[10, 20, 30],
        [40, 50, 60]]
```

how would you use append() to make data as:

```
>>> data
[[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
```

Comment: Which language python?

Comment: yes lang is python!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, just pass the part you want to include in the list `[70, 80, 90]` (as you call it tuple) to the `.append()` method of the data list, see below.

```
data = [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60]]
data.append([70, 80, 90])
print(data)
```

Be wary however that in python a tuple is a different data type then a list. Both can contain multiple elements, but they have the key difference that tuples are immutable (not changeable after assigned). [Here](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-tuples-vs-lists/) is a tutorial on differences between lists and tuples in python

In Python this

```
a = (2,3,4)
print(a)
```

Is a **immutable tuple**

And this

```
a = [2,3,4]
print(a)
```

Is a **mutable list**.